# Converting foreign characters in english characters in Java

Tags: java, string, converters, string-conversion

I need to read an XML file that contains the names of countries in english and in several other languages.

I'm putting them in a HashMap after reading them in, but some of them use non-English characters.

Example: `Afghanistan` in Serbian(I think) is `Авганистан`

When reading it in and printing it out to the console, the value is displayed as `????????`

How can I Work around this?

Answer (score 0):

One solutions is to change the encoding of your Ide, for example if you uses Eclipse you go where you run the project (run configurations) and put in the vm the following sentence  -Dfile.encoding=cp1252 with for example you allow accents and spanish characters.